# message shows undefined when ajax post in ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Hi I'm Fairly new at coding and in asp.net and had an error occurred to me please help me if you can. This is my script when I run the code given below using an onclick function the success message shows as undefined and c# function SaveData which I placed in break point doesn't hit. clearly the post didnt reach the server function.

text1 and text2 are two variables

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Default.aspx/SaveData",
    data: "{dataval: '" + text1 + "', dataval1: '" + text2 + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
});
```

server side

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveData(string dataval, string dataval1)
{
    string data = String.Format("Your Name is {0} and address is {1}", dataval, dataval1);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `contentType` from your `AJAX` call and then try.

Comment: Checked same problem not reaching SaveData but not showing success message now

Comment: This C# method is default get, try using type: "GET" in your ajax method and check ... or make c# method "POST"

Answer (score 1):

I have created this sample and working fine. Please check below answer.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/SaveData",
        data: { dataval: 'asd', dataval1: 'asd' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            alert(data);
        },
        });
    });
```

Backend

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SaveData(string dataval, string dataval1)
    {
        string data = String.Format("Your Name is {0} and address is {1}", dataval, dataval1);
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I hope this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the answer to my problem. The problem was with commenting a piece of code in **RouteConfig.cs** file in **App_Start** folder.

```
 //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Don't know why but it worked fine after this. Please let me know how this works.